# Send E-mail from javascript using REST API

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint-email

I want to send email using Javascript/jQuery using REST API in SharePoint.

I have tried `_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail` and this is my code:

### Code

```
$.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: urlEmail,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({
                  'properties': {
                  '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Utilities.EmailProperties' },
                  'Body': 'Hello',
                  'To' : { 'results': ['kaushal.khamar@xxxxxx.com'] },
                  'Subject': "From REST API"
                }
            }),
        headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
                },
        success: function (data) {
                alert("Successful");
                },
        error: function (err) {
                alert(err.responseText);
                }
        });
```

### Error

> The e-mail message cannot be sent. Make sure the e-mail has a valid recipient.

Comment: Please add your code block to get more clarity of your exception.

Comment: Reason of which i am getting while sending emails is i have added Email address of mine which is not included in any sharepoint user. Thats why i am getting error like **"The e-mail message cannot be sent. Make sure the e-mail has a valid recipient"**. So whenever try to send mails make sure that email should be email address one of the users of sharepoint.

Comment: @KaushalKhamar: how about not advertising your own blog which contains the same information as posted here?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In `SharePoint 2013 On Premise` we can send emails using `REST API` where we can utilise `SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail` for doing the job.

> Note: The recipient is limited to a valid SharePoint user for security
>   reasons.

```
function processSendEmails() {

    var from = 'asad@Example.com',
        to = 'someone@Example.com',
        body = 'Hello World Body',
        subject = 'Hello World Subject';

    // Call sendEmail function
    //
    sendEmail(from, to, body, subject);
}


function sendEmail(from, to, body, subject) {
    //Get the relative url of the site
    var siteurl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;
    var urlTemplate = siteurl + "/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail";
    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: urlTemplate,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            'properties': {
                '__metadata': {
                    'type': 'SP.Utilities.EmailProperties'
                },
                'From': from,
                'To': {
                    'results': [to]
                },
                'Body': body,
                'Subject': subject
            }
        }),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert('Email Sent Successfully');
        },
        error: function(err) {
            alert('Error in sending Email: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', processSendEmails);

});
```

Comment: Hi, I used _spPageContextInfo.userLoginName to get the current logged in user email address. It worked, but when I see the mail it shows From value as "no-reply@sharepointonline.com". How can I get actual email address here?

Comment: You mean to say, you used `var from = spPageContextInfo.userLoginName,` in the function. but the From address shows "no-reply@sharepointonline.com"?

Comment: yes...you got the right.

Comment: I am afraid I have not tried it in SPO.

Comment: i want to send HTML in body example:-
 var body='<html><body><a>click here</a></body></html>';

how we can do this?@AsadRefai

Comment: @SavanGupta Did you tried setting this html in body variable and executed the code?

Comment: yes i have tried.. @AsadRefai

Comment: @SavanGupta what was the result? any error?

Comment: @AsadRefai.. It was only a plain text in email. i wanted to create a meeting invite so i was thinking to send  ical file. Can we send meeting invite directly using rest api?

Comment: @AsadRefai any solution?

Comment: @SavanGupta I am unsure about meeting invites. I have never tried that.

Comment: @AsadRefai, What if I want to include multiple receiver(To) in the email?

Comment: Hey @AsadRefai I am getting this error.

Comment: Error in sending Email: {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"error\":{\"code\":\"-2130575252, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException\",\"message\":{\"lang\":\"en-US\",\"value\":\"The security validation for this page is invalid and might be corrupted. Please use your web browser's Back button to try your operation again.\"}}}","responseJSON":{"error":{"code":"-2130575252, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The security validation for this page is invalid and might be corrupted. Please use your web browser's Back button to try your operation again."}}},"status":403,...

Comment: @AsadRefai ,  is it possible to use this code for SP Online on a button click of new form.aspx file of my SPO list

Comment: @SaMolPP Yes this should work in SP Online as well.However in your `newform.aspx` you should figure out a way to call this function from JS file. In classic UI may be exploring JSLink would be helpful.

Comment: This code was working , but now its like alert is coming but its not sending mail (some are able to but some not )

Answer (score 5):

Please refer this [link](http://geekswithblogs.net/ThorvaldBoe/archive/2014/07/03/sending-email-with-sharepoint-and-jquery.aspx) for for detailed code, you shall realize the issue.

This [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3add7664-d156-494d-a56f-3213cf9fff54/sending-email-with-apisputilitiesutilitysendemail?forum=appsforsharepoint) is also useful.

Also: Make sure that the recipient is limited to a valid SharePoint user for security reasons.

Info: You have to provide the sharepoint Id for the specific user in order to send this user an email!

The following is the code:

```
function sendEmail(from, to, body, subject) {
//Get the relative url of the site
var siteurl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;
var urlTemplate = siteurl + "/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail";
$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: urlTemplate,
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        'properties': {
            '__metadata': {
                'type': 'SP.Utilities.EmailProperties'
            },
            'From': from,
            'To': {
                'results': [to]
            },
            'Body': body,
            'Subject': subject
        }
    }),
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert('Email Sent Successfully');
    },
    error: function(err) {
        alert('Error in sending Email: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
    }
});
}
```

Please make sure that the email recipient is in the same domain as SP server.

Comment: i have go through this article and implemented same but getting error like "The e-mail message cannot be sent. Make sure the e-mail has a valid recipient". I dont know why this error occur. Send to email id is valid one. still getting error.

Comment: Try one thing - rather than writing the email id leave it as 'results': [to] abd check what happens. I feel it is this line that is giving error.

Comment: I have tried this but still not working...

Comment: Can you add details from the link in your answer? Link only answers become invalid should the links break.

Comment: Error in sending Email: {"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"} . I was getting this error  when i changed this =_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl to =_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function I have added and call it like

```
sendEmail("domain\\sender", "domain\\recipient","This is the body","Mail Subject");:


    var hostweburl;
    var appweburl;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', sendEmail);
    });
    function sendEmail(from, to, body, subject) {    
    appweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter('SPAppWebUrl'));
    hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter('SPHostUrl'));
    var urlTemplate = appweburl + "/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail";
    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: urlTemplate,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            'properties': {
                '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Utilities.EmailProperties' },
                'From': from,
                'To': { 'results': [to] },
                'Body': body,
                'Subject': subject
            }
        }
      ),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
           console.log('success')
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
        }
    });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wan to send e-mails outside the tenant, to any email,
you can do a workaround with MS Flow.

Trigger it with HTTP REST Call from your SharePoint,
with input parameters: recepient, subject, email body.

and add a send e-mail action to your flow.

See: https://medium.com/@zaab_it/microsoft-flow-send-email-from-http-request-f6577ad46b2c

Answer (score 0):

[This blog is explains the issue very well](http://zsvipullo.blogspot.de/2016/06/sputilitysendemail-400-bad-request-e.html#!/2016/06/sputilitysendemail-400-bad-request-e.html).

Summary of the blog:

> What that MSDN define as
>
> valid SharePoint user email addresses
>
> means:
>
> a user that has or had permissions in this site and then belong to All
>   People SharePoint Hidden Group.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to the game on this, but hopefully this can help someone else with this headbanging error who's scouring for an answer -- "*The e-mail message cannot be sent. Make sure the e-mail has a valid recipient.*" -- persists even when sent to valid recipients within the same SharePoint domain from within the same server (for instance, if sent to an MS Exchange Shared Mailbox - as was my experience).

After some research, I was able to find a purely front-end solution to overcome this issue (because every other forum solution for the most part proposed SPD, but I was looking to stick to strictly CSOM/JSOM.

Anyways, the solution is to **add the Shared Mailbox's email address to an existing "Members" SP group within the site collection** (used in conjunction within user Asad Refai's REST API call, and emails will send to that particular Shared Mailbox).  As soon as I did this, the "*Valid recipient*" error subsided and emails were received to the Shared Mailbox from the server.