# SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail "To" must be different format for some users

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, email, sharepoint-on-prem

I am having trouble with sending emails via REST in javascript following the answer in this question:

[Send E-mail from javascript using REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/148226/send-e-mail-from-javascript-using-rest-api)

My issue is that emails, for some users, are only sent successfully if they are in the format `domain\\user` or the `'To'` property. Other users this will not work and their actual email address , `username@somesite.com`, must be used.

Emails from alerts and workflows work without issue.

Comment: Can you post the script you are using?

Comment: You should able be passing email addresses to the To parameter. Are you passing something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Searching users in powershell would return two users for some people. Using the cmdlet:

`Get-SPUser -web http://somesite.com | ?{$_.DisplayName -eq "john doe"}`

Results:

> ```
> UserLogin                    DisplayName   
> ---------                    -----------   
> i:0#.w|domain\john-doe       John Doe
> DOMAIN\john-doe              John Doe
> ```

The email address would be the same for both spusers. When attempting to send the email using `john-doe@somesite.com` I believe there was a conflict when trying to resolve the email to a single user and would result in error.

Changing the `'To'` addresses to the format `i:0#.w|domain\\username` resolved the issue and I was able to send emails to any spuser successfully.

Comment: Now to figure why some people have two accounts

Comment: super cool! please post your findings here! Thanks!