# Ajax email 2013 SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail group mailbox

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-email

Has anyone found a method of sending emails to group mailboxes using SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail?

The technique is described here

[Send E-mail from javascript using REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/148226/send-e-mail-from-javascript-using-rest-api/148233#148233)

and the basic code works well.

The requirements are that all email addresses must be on the same domain, which my group email box is, but I still get the error stating "The e-mail message cannot be sent. Make sure the e-mail has a valid recipient."

Questions

1. In the above post, it mentions that the domain can also be added to the send command, but an example of this is not mentioned - has anyone tried this method?
2. In several alerts I've set up, the user id was defined as i:0#.w|internal\myid - is it possible to use this format to get around this error?
3. Going into a List, and selecting "Manage My Alerts" > "Create New Alert" then select the list brings you to a screen that allows you to enter a User to be notified. The group mailbox can be entered here, and is verified, but then when selecting OK, I get the message

   "The user does not exist or is not unique. 
    Technical Details 
    Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. 
    Correlation ID: 5386599d-6269-00d3-be65-6e6dbe3ef328"

   So how come it verified the ID on the screen, but then it errored out?
    How can I get my group mailbox registered as a valid user?

I don't have access to SP Workflows, so this option is not available to me.