# Is it possible to specify the FROM email address in the "Send an Email" action?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I'm using SharePoint Designer 2013 have a Cloud installation. So far it looks like this cannot be done out-of-box and some of the 3rd party sites I've seen do not reference 2013-- only older versions.

Does anyone have a decent solution for 2013 cloud SharePoint?

Comment: `_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail` http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/148226/send-e-mail-from-javascript-using-rest-api

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to change the FROM address in "Send an Email" step.

Answer (score 0):

By default you could not change "From" address in SPD workflow.

You should use custom or third-party send email activity.