# SharePoint 2013 Infopath 2010 form Send e-mail From user created this form

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, infopath

I am novice in SharePoint 2013. I have task to customize Infopath 2010 form so that the user created this form  can automatically send the email with data and attached PDF file to recipient.

I found here the post [send email from javascript using REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/148226/send-e-mail-from-javascript-using-rest-api)

How to add this code to SharePoint 2013?

How use this code in info path form?

Are any other methods there to customize info path form to send from user created this form?