# How to add C# code in default.aspx and call that C# code using javascript in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I added a custom button on a display form of a list.And I want to call C# code on a click of button,that will send a email to outlook,using JavaScript.

So where i should put the C# code in SharePoint online, so that i would be able to call that code.

C# Code for sending an email-

```
 class mainProgram
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        eAppointmentMail mailTo = new SendEmail.eAppointmentMail();
        mailTo.Body = "Mail Body";
        mailTo.Email = "exp@outlook.com";
        mailTo.EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
        mailTo.Location = "Skype";
        mailTo.Name = "Arzoo Soni";
        mailTo.StartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(8);
        mailTo.Subject = "Subject of the mail";
        Console.WriteLine(SendAnInvitation.sendOutlookInvitationViaICSFile(mailTo));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}



class SendAnInvitation
{
    public static string sendOutlookInvitationViaICSFile(eAppointmentMail objApptEmail)
    {
        try
        {
            //Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath);
            //MailSettingsSectionGroup settings = (MailSettingsSectionGroup)config.GetSectionGroup("system.net/mailSettings");

            SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

            System.Net.Mail.MailMessage msg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();

            msg.From = new MailAddress("arzoosoni4@gmail.com");
            msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(objApptEmail.Email, objApptEmail.Name));
            msg.Subject = objApptEmail.Subject;
            msg.Body = objApptEmail.Body;
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR");
            str.AppendLine("PRODID:-//" + objApptEmail.Email);
            str.AppendLine("VERSION:2.0");
            str.AppendLine("METHOD:REQUEST");
            str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VEVENT");

            str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTART:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", objApptEmail.StartDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMdd\\THHmmss\\Z")));
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTAMP:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", (objApptEmail.EndDate - objApptEmail.StartDate).Minutes.ToString()));
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTEND:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", objApptEmail.EndDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMdd\\THHmmss\\Z")));
            //str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTART:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", objApptEmail.StartDate.ToString()));
            //str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTAMP:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", DateTime.UtcNow));
            //str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTEND:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", objApptEmail.EndDate.ToString()));
            str.AppendLine("LOCATION:" + objApptEmail.Location);
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("DESCRIPTION:{0}", objApptEmail.Body));
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:{0}", objApptEmail.Body));
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("SUMMARY:{0}", objApptEmail.Subject));
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("ORGANIZER:MAILTO:{0}", objApptEmail.Email));
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("ATTENDEE;CN=\"{0}\";RSVP=TRUE:mailto:{1}", msg.To[0].DisplayName, msg.To[0].Address));
            str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VALARM");
            str.AppendLine("TRIGGER:-PT15M");
            str.AppendLine("ACTION:DISPLAY");
            str.AppendLine("DESCRIPTION:Reminder");
            str.AppendLine("END:VALARM");
            str.AppendLine("END:VEVENT");
            str.AppendLine("END:VCALENDAR");
            System.Net.Mime.ContentType ct = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/calendar");
            ct.Parameters.Add("method", "REQUEST");
            AlternateView avCal = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(str.ToString(), ct);
            msg.AlternateViews.Add(avCal);
            NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential("****@gmail.com", "password");
            sc.Port = 25;
            sc.EnableSsl = true;
            sc.Credentials = nc;
            try
            {
                sc.Send(msg);
                return "Success";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return "Fail";
            }
        }
        catch { }
        return string.Empty;
    }
}

public class eAppointmentMail
{
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public string Email { set; get; }
    public string Location { set; get; }
    public DateTime StartDate { set; get; }
    public DateTime EndDate { set; get; }
    public string Subject { set; get; }
    public string Body { set; get; }
}
```

Please give me solution related to my problem.

Answer (score 4):

C# code (Managed Code) is depreciated in SharePoint Online. So you cannot do this directly.

So What is the workaround?

You can create an `.NET Web API` and write your C# code into that. And just call that `.NET Web API` using your JavaScript REST API.

But in .NET Web API, the problem will be in authentication. There you have to manually authenticate by providing **Site URL, Username and Password** as a plain text.

Also, if you are not aware then I would like to tell you that there are email REST API are already available with SharePoint Online. You can send emails using that REST API's.

[Send email using REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/148226/send-e-mail-from-javascript-using-rest-api)