# Send mail to "Shared Mail Box" address using JSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, email, sharepoint-rest-api, sharepoint-email

I am able to send mail using this article :

[Send E-mail from javascript using REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/148226/send-e-mail-from-javascript-using-rest-api)

What changes do I need to make to send email to a "Shared Mail Box" email address.?