# How to get contents of a form send in the email

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am trying to get the contents of a form to send in an email. Below is the code but it does not add the text to the email.

```
<form method="post" action="mailto:emailaddress@co.uk.com">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="MR">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Test">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="send email" />
</form>
```

​

Comment: <html>
<body>

<form method="post" action="mailto:emailaddress@co.uk.com">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="MR">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Test">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="send email" />
</form> 


​<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input  type="text" name="firstname" id="fstName"/>
<input  type="text" name="lastname" id="lstName"/>
```

to get value of those textbox use this:

```
FirstName= $("#fstName").val();
LastName= $("#lstName").val();
```

Comment: Where do I put that bit of code though Thanks

Comment: I have added the id="fstName"/> part but where do I add the val( ); to the code.

Comment: It's a JQuey you can create a Submit function to get value and send it via Mail

Comment: I have added the code but still it does not add the content when I select submit to the email. Below is the full code that I have.

Comment: <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   FirstName= $("#fstName").val();
LastName= $("#lstName").val();
 });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="mailto:email@co.uk">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" id="fstName" /> 
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lstName" /> 
  <br><br>
  <strong>
  <input type="submit" value="Send Email" /></strong>
</form>

Comment: Please read about how to send Emai https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/148259/42224