# How to add attachment with default send by mail functionality in SharePoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, send-email

Is it possible to send an e-mail with attachment in Office 365? As attachment we would want the attachment from a list item or local system or a document from a document library.

I tried using a SMTP server in a custom webpart (which failed because SMTP isn't allowed)

Is this solution possible?

I had written below code for send by mail.

```
$(document).on('click',"button[data-automation-id='sendByEmailDialogSendButton']", function (event) {
    loadScript("https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js", function(){
        debugger;
        Email.send({
            SecureToken: "35c2dcb7-b282-47ce-b894-4fe52a3f071a",
            Host : "smtp.gmail.com",
            port:"587",
            EnableSsl :false,
            Username : "Gmail Username",
            Password : "password",
            To : 'SharePOint Id(admin@222.onmicrosoft.com)',
            From : "Gmail Id(abc@gmail.com)",
            Subject : "Send by admin",
            Body : "And this is the body"}).then( message => alert(message));
    });
```

**Throwing error** “The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Authentication Required.”

Answer (score 0):

To send email from SharePoint, using JavaScript, then you can use [SP.Utilities.EmailProperties object (sp.js)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj246895(v=office.15)?redirectedfrom=MSDN), it has the following properties,

```
From, To, CC, BCC, Subject, Body ,
```

it doesn't have any property for `attachments`

As an alternate, you can upload the document into a library and send the link over emails.

For more information, refer the below links,

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/send-email-with-attachment-in-office-365-sharepoint-online/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27377376/how-do-i-send-email-with-inline-attachments

For complete code to send email from SharePoint without attachment, refer this [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/148226/send-e-mail-from-javascript-using-rest-api)